# Search a struct nested in an array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, struct

I have a struct that's inside an array that is nested inside another struct, like so: `Arguments.cart.data.Items[x].Labels.Pkg.Title` (`x` is an index, as I'm looping over `Items`).

`Items` is an array while `Labels`, `Pkg`, and `Title` are nested structs.

`Title` does not always exist. So I would like to check for it. However, using `structFindKey` returns an error

> You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members

I could just look inside `Arguments.cart.data`; however, if there are multiple rows in the array, some rows may contain `Title` while others do not. So I want to check for `Title` inside each `Items`.

I've also tried `arrayFind`, but then I get the error

> Struct cannot be used as an array

I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job

```
<cfscript>
    for (i=1;i<=ArrayLen(arguments.cart.data.Items);i++) {
        tempI = arguments.cart.data.Items[i];
        if (IsDefined('tempI.Labels.Pkg.Title')) {
            // It exists
        } else {
            // It doesn't
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

IsDefined doesn't play nicely with arrays, but by assigning each element of the array to the temp value you are then able to refer to it within IsDefined.

Alternatively you can do the following, if you prefer StructKeyExists

```
<cfscript>
    for (i=1;i<=ArrayLen(arguments.cart.data.Items);i++) {
        tempI = arguments.cart.data.Items[i];
        if (
            StructKeyExists(tempI,'Labels')
            && StructKeyExists(tempI.Labels,'Pkg')
            && StructKeyExists(tempI.Labels.Pkg,'Title')
        ) {
            // It exists
        } else {
            // It doesn't
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this in the past too.  Just stick your array into a struct temporarily... this will trick `structFindKey()` and `structFindValue()` into working properly.